# Concat Two IQueryables with Anonymous Types?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I've been wrestling with this a little while and it's starting to look like it may not be possible.

I want to `Concat()` two `IQueryable`s and then execute the result as a single query. I tried something like this:

```
var query = from x in ...
select new
{
    A = ...
    B = ...
    C = ...
};

var query2 = from y in ...
select new
{
    A = ...
    B = ...
    C = ...
};

var query3 = query.Concat(query2);
```

However, the last line gives me the following error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Concat(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

It appears it's expecting an `IEnumerable` for the argument. Is there any way around this?

It looks like I could resolve both queries to `IEnumerable`s and then `Concat()` them. But it would be more efficient to create a single query, and it seems like that should be possible.

Comment: Types with like properties aren't one and the same, I think, so your enumerables are of different (anonymous) types. I think that's why you can't concatenate them. The easiest solution is to just use an class/interface.

Comment: They aren't IEnumerables, they're IQueryables. I'm not sure about your suggestion. I could define a type if needed, but it's not clear how SQL Server will handle that.

Comment: What is the type of `query` and `query2`? `IQueryable<>` and `IQueryable<>`? What of the types of `A`, `B` and `C` in each of the corresponding queries? Are they the same?

Comment: IQueryables *are* IEnumerables. Concat is defined at the level of IEnumerable, so whether it is an IQueryable or a List or some other subtype of IEnumerable is irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I'm not sure I understand the question. My code shows how they are declared. They are anonymous types. Can you clarify if you would like more information?

Comment: @Asad: Not sure I follow. I think of `IQueryable` as a query ready to be converted to SQL. And I think of `IEnumerable` as the results of a query.

Comment: You've left out the most critical parts of the queries, their types. I see `query` and `query2` are collections of somethings from some source. Knowing that source is critical here so we know if we're dealing purely with LINQ to Objects, EF, LINQ to SQL, etc. The error message you show is a bit misleading. You don't necessarily have parallel queries, it's just the compiler trying to spit out potentially useful information on how to resolve the error.

Comment: it's weird that it's working on .net fiddle [LINK](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F9KwzS)

Comment: @JeffMercado: They are both Entity Framework queries, selecting data from my database. I'm trying to produce a single SQL query.

Comment: Are each from the same context? I don't know if EF allows for cross database queries or ones from different contexts. You may have to combine them using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Are you sure `A`, `B` and `C` from the first query have the same data type as `A`, `B` and `C` from the second, respectively? Also, `IQueryable<T>` is `interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>`, so it should accept the 2nd argument anyways. It seems the argument is invalid because they return different objects.

Comment: @Johnny: Looks like query is `System.Linq.IQueryable<<>f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,Leo.Domain.Employee,int,string,string>> {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,Leo.Domain.Employee,int,string,string>>}`, and query2 is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,Leo.Domain.Employee,int?,string,string>> {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Leo.Domain.HotelFileItem,<>f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,Leo.Domain.Employee,int?,string,string>>}`

Comment: There you go, one has nullable int, the other doesn't.

Comment: @lastr2d2: That's just Linq, not Entity Framework or IQueryables.

Comment: @JeffMercado: They are from the same database context, but definitely from different tables. SQL's UNION ALL can do this and so can Linq, I was hoping I could do the same thing with Entity Framework. Yes, if this won't work I'll have to run two queries and Concat the results.

Comment: @ConradClark: BINGO! I screwed up. In one I had `int` where in the other I had `int?` What a stupid mistake. Your comment caused me to carefully verify each field and one didn't match. If you repost as an answer, I will give credit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

As you said previously in the comments, it seems that the two queries return different objects:

Query 1 (as per comment):

```
f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,Leo.Domain.Employ‌​ee,int,string,string>
```

Query2 is

```
f__AnonymousTypee<Leo.Domain.FileItem,L‌​eo.Domain.Employee,int?,string,string>
```

This is why `Concat` is giving you an error message complaining about invalid arguments.

Comment: Yep, this turned out to be the issue. I'm so glad this is possible. It seems much more efficient than the alternatives. Looks like I still have some errors, but this one now compiles.

Comment: @JonathanWood I might be missing something, but this answer doesn't actually provide a solution. It just reiterates the problem highlighted in the comments above.

Comment: @Asad: The comments above is what let me to find the problem. I appreciate everyone's help on this, but I told Conrad I'd accept his answer if he reiterated the issue we discussed in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous objects will be equivalent types to other anonymous objects with the same property names and types declared in exactly the same order.

Assuming both `query` and `query2` from from the same contexts, you should be able to combine the two, provided they are queries of equivalent types.

Your comment indicates that neither are of the same type.

`query` returns objects of type `Anon<FileItem, Employee, int, string, string>`
`query2` returns objects of type `Anon<FileItem, Employee, int?, string, string>`.

You cannot combine the two because they are of different types.  You'll need to make sure that both queries return objects of the same type.

```
var query = from x in ...
    select new
    {
        A = (FileItem)...
        B = (Employee)...
        C = (int)...
        ...
    };

var query2 = from y in ...
    select new
    {
        A = (FileItem)...
        B = (Employee)...
        C = (int)...
        ...
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The IDE determined query and query2 are of different types, while the IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>() extension method expects two same types (IEnumerable<TSource>). The three TSource's must be the same.

```
string[] strA = {"123", "234", "345"};
int[] intA = { 1, 2, 3 };
var query = from s in strA
            select s;
var query2 = from i in strA // intA
                select i;
var query3 = query.Concat(query2);
```

Uncomment "// intA" in VS and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Even though the two anonymous types look the same they are two different types.

The most-readable-code approach in this is case is to declare a type to Select your values into for your two queries.  Then the Concat will be working on a single type and do what you need.

You haven't specified the types of `A`, `B` or `C` so I'm going to cast them to `TypeA`, `TypeB`, and `TypeC` and make them properties of collections of `SomeType` for purposes of demonstrating `Concat`.

```
class Result
{
    public TypeA A { get; }
    public TypeB B { get; }
    public TypeC C { get; }

    public Result(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}

ICollection<SomeType> source1;
ICollection<SomeType> source2;

// sources get populated here somehow

var result1 = source1.Select(_ => new Result(_.A, _.B, _.C));
var result2 = source2.Select(_ => new Result(_.A, _.B, _.C));
var results = result1.Concat(result2);
```

Comment: If you answer this because you don't like the accepted answer (and *how* it was accepted), IMO a better answer would be making both types equal (e.g. by using a cast to `int?` in one query). That also contributes to *understanding* the issue, a work-around doesn't. Also, if the types were all strings, the issue wouldn't even exist.

Comment: `Union()` is what I needed.

Comment: @GertArnold I only cast to string because the types of `A,` `B`, and `C` were not provided and I wanted to maintain the OPs code in the answer.  Given it was a bit too vague I've edited my answer by stating some assumptions and providing a clearer example.  It's now difficult to see where the anonymous types feed into to the Concat now but hopefully it doesn't lead to further confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing any namespace? Normally I mark my .NET Project Properties to target .net 4.0 for vs 2010. I do not use .net 4.0 Client Profile.

Please make sure that the types of A, B and C is matches in both the query anonymous types. Also the order of A, B and C should also match in both queries.

The following example works like a charm.

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        private static void BuildList()
        {
            employees.AddRange(
                new Employee[]
                    {
                        new Employee() {Name = "Tom", Age = 22, Address = "sample1", Salary = 10000},
                        new Employee() {Name = "Mithun", Age = 27, Address = "sample1", Salary = 20000},
                        new Employee() {Name = "Jasubhai", Age = 24, Address = "sample1", Salary = 12000},
                        new Employee() {Name = "Vinod", Age = 34, Address = "sample1", Salary = 30000},
                        new Employee() {Name = "Iqbal", Age = 52, Address = "sample1", Salary = 50000},
                        new Employee() {Name = "Gurpreet", Age = 22, Address = "sample1", Salary = 10000},

                    }
                );
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildList();
            var query = from employee in employees
                        where employee.Age < 27
                        select new
                            {
                                A = employee.Name,
                                B = employee.Age,
                                C = employee.Salary
                            };


            var query2 = from employee in employees
                         where employee.Age > 27
                         select new
                             {
                                 A = employee.Name,
                                 B = employee.Age,
                                 C = employee.Salary
                             };

            var result = query.Concat(query2);

            foreach (dynamic item in result.ToArray())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Age = {1}, Salary = {2}", item.A, item.B, item.C);
            }
        }


    }
}
```